# Uncaught Exception occured in ExecutorService

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, executorservice

I have a springboot application that getting large number of requests. In my application its not responding at a time. When I check the server logs to identify issues there are no any memory or any other issues. But I saw that there are some `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` logged. When check the relevant code this is throw in a thread and its not handled.

Sample is as below (This is not the original code),

```
try {
            ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size);
            
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                DataController workerThread = new DataController(i, resultsList);
                
                threadPool.execute(workerThread);
            }
            
            threadPool.shutdown();
            boolean isTerminated = threadPool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            
            System.out.println("isTerminated::"+ isTerminated);
            
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


class DataController implements Runnable {

    private int i;
    private List<String>[] resultsList;
    
    
    public DataController(int i, List<String>[] resultsList) {
        this.i = i;
        this.resultsList = resultsList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add(String.valueOf(i));
        
        if(i==2) {
            i = 2/0;
        }
        
        this.resultsList[this.i] = a;
    }
    
}
```

My problem is, as like this if there is any exception throw in a ExecutorService thread is there any performance issues happening? If its is happens then adding try-catch is enough?

Comment: The uncaught exception is very unlikely to be the cause of your performance issues.

Comment: In the monitoring graphs other metrics not show any problems. But there is no graphs to check threads in my environment. Because of that I'm thinking is there any problem can be happens with this exception.

Comment: Just try fixing your array-index bug *and* add a try-catch around your `run` method’s code to trap any further such exceptions. See for yourself if that solves the problem. If so, post your own Answer to your Question. Tip: Make a habit of always using a try-catch around the code in all your `run`/`call` methods. A scheduled executor service will stop further task executions if an exception or error bubbles up.